# Conditionally Joining One of Two Tables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to join one of two tables to a third table based on a logical evaluation. In this highly simplified example, I would like `result` to end up with the values from `df2` since in this case `option == 2`.

**Example Data:**

```
df1 <- tibble(index = 1:5)
df2 <- tibble(index = 1:5, value = 1:5)
df3 <- tibble(index = 1:5, value = 10*1:5)

option <- 2
```

**What I've tried:**

```
# Method 1
result <- df1 %>%
  left_join(if_else(option == 2, df2, df3), by = "index")

# Error: Can't use NA as column index with `[` at position 1.

# Method 2
result <- df1 %>%
  if (option == 2){
    left_join(df2, by = "index")
  } else {
    left_join(df3, by = "index")
  }

# Error in if (.) option == 2 else { : 
# argument is not interpretable as logical

# Method 3
result <- if_else(option == 2, 
              df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "index"),
              df1 %>% left_join(df3, by = "index")
          )

# Error: Can't use NA as column index with `[` at position 1.
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pipe directory into an `if` statement. You could pipe in a block and then `maggrittr` defines the `.` variable for the data that was passed in. So you could so

```
result <- df1 %>% {
  if (option == 2){
    left_join(., df2, by = "index")
  } else {
    left_join(., df3, by = "index")
  }
}
```

But even better it probably to keep your other data.frames in a list and then index into the list with your `option` value

```
others <- list( df2, df3)
result <- df1 %>% left_join(others[[option]], by = "index")
```

You can also use names with this method

```
others <- list(aa=df2, bb=df3)
option <- "aa"
result <- df1 %>% left_join(others[[option]], by = "index")
```

You can't use `if_else` because that's a vectorized function, not a control flow function. It's not meant to return objects that are a different size that the input condition.

Comment: Thanks! Really like the list approach. I did realize that `others[[aa]]` should be `others[[option]]`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Teddly Good point. I fixed the mistake in the post

Answer (score 3):

Another option below. I agree having a named list and choosing a name rather than numeric option is probably better though.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df1 <- tibble(index = 1:5)
df2 <- tibble(index = 1:5, value = 1:5)
df3 <- tibble(index = 1:5, value = 10*1:5)

option <- 2

df1 %>%
  left_join(if (option == 2) df2 else df3, by = "index")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   index value
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     3     3
#> 4     4     4
#> 5     5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>